# Weiner Increments for Products of Noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, noise

In the construction of a Langevin equation, how would one handle an equation that looks like $\dot x=\xi_1\xi_2$? I understand that, for an equation like $\dot x = \xi$ one can write $dx=dW$ (Weiner process) but I don't understand what to do with $dx=dt(\frac{dW_1}{dt}\frac{dW_2}{dt})$. Thanks!

Comment: White noise is a distribution. The multiplication of two distributions is not well defined.

Comment: Even if the product of two distributions is not well defined, the product of two random variables is so would it be possible to go down that line of reasoning?

Comment: They are distribution-valued random variables. So, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Does that mean that this problem is unsolvable? I.e. that there is no mathematical framework for handling an SDE with a a product of stochastic variables?

Comment: The problem is ill-posed, there is no point in talking about solvability. There are ways to define a multiplication of distributions, but not in a canonical way.  That's not a probability issue, but rather a functional analysis one.

Comment: There are plenty of times where such an equation would arise, take for example a rectangle with independent and stochastically growing length and width. In the equation for the time derivative for the area of the rectangle, there would be a product of stochastic variables. I apologies if the initial wording of the question is unclear, but that is the type of equation I am trying to reconcile here.

Comment: Staying with your example, for your side length you must not take a distribution valued process, but a real-valued one. E.g. it's fine to say both side lengths grow like two indpendent Brownian motion $B^{1}_{t}$ and $B^{2}_{t}$, and set $A_{t}:=B^{1}_{t}B^{2}_{t}$. This object is perfectely well defined. It's derivative however, ought to be understood again only in distributional sense.